# Spanish to German dictionary on English OS

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, dictionary

is it somehow possible to add a dictionary for two different foreign languages to the Dictionary app?
I am using macOS 10.15 "Catalina" in English and I would like to add a Spanish to German dictionary.
Adding a Spanish and a German dictionary is possible. Also also the Dictionary app allows us to add english to german and English to Spanish, but I do not see the the option to add German-Spanish.

Can someone help if this is even feasible? When yes, how can I add this dictionary?

Here is the list of options I have.

[image]

Comment: Check this page.   http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2013/01/adding-dictionaries-to-dictionaryapp.html

Answer (score 0):

I have added other dictionaries to the list, but they have to be in the right format.  At the moment, I am not able to look up documentation for the format.